# Can't locate Config.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

I have a Perl app on my development server that I would like to replicate on my local machine (mac osx). I'm not a perl programmer by trade (I'm a PHP/Rails developer), and the developer of this app is no longer around so I can't contact him for help. I've gotten pretty close to getting it to work. I was able to install all the packages using CPAN (at least I think I got them all) but I keep running into the following error:

```
Can't locate WebCNP/Config.pm in @INC (
    @INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
                   /Library/Perl/5.16 
                   /Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
                   /Network/Library/Perl/5.16 
                   /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
                   /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2 
                   /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
                   /System/Library/Perl/5.16 
                   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
                   /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16 .
    ) 
    at webcnp_lib.pl line 30.
```

On the server, the app's file structure looks like this:

```
/var/www/cgi-bin (empty dir)
/var/www/conf
/var/www/error
/var/www/html (empty dir)
/var/www/icons
/var/www/perl (the config file is located in this directory)
    - /WebCNP/Config.pm
/var/www/ssi (all the .pl files for the app are located here, including all the JS and CSS files)
```

Line 30 of `/var/www/ssi/webcnp_lib.pl` has the following:

```
use WebCNP::Config;
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Just so you know I've copied the file structure of the app from my development server to my local machine and created a virtual host so that it points to the app's root directory (/var/www).

Thanks in advanced for any insight!

Comment: You apparently did not install all the packages, since the error says that `WebCNP::Config` is missing. Install it.

Comment: @TLP — It clearly is installed. It is shown in the file structure described in the question. The problem is that `@INC` does not include that directory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718918/how-to-override-inc-settings-in-httpd-conf-on-osx looks like *almost* a duplicate, but I'm not sure the accepted answer is detailed enough.

Comment: @Quentin It is debatable whether one can call it a correct installation when the module is not installed in a place where Perl usually looks for it. Rather than try and fix a broken installation, do it properly from the beginning.

Comment: It isn't a CPAN module, so I wouldn't be surprised if the install instructions are "Unzip this set of directories under your web root".

Comment: @Quentin You are correct. The little instructions that there are say to unzip it in your root. I'll into that thread posted above and see where I get. Thanks for all your input! I'll update this post when my findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> was able to fix this with a symbolic link
>
> `ln -s /path/to/my/app/WebCNP /Library/Perl/5.16/WebCNP`

I take this isn't a module from CPAN.

I would be a bit hesitant to use a symbolic link. This will work, but you're basically linking in a file you have under your own control to the master `/Library` directory on MacOS X.  You delete your file, and that link won't be pointing to anything.

You can use `use lib` to add directories that contain your modules to the `@INC` directory:

```
use lib qw(/path/to/my/app);
```

This will now include this path for module searches.

If you rather install the module itself, why not simply copy it into `/Lbrary/Perl/5.16` itself? It's what `cpan` would have done. At least this way, you're Perl module directory isn't dependent upon a link that can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

`/var/www/perl` isn't present in `@INC`, so Perl won't look there. The most common approach to solve this for CGI scripts would be to add the following to your scripts (but not modules):

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/../perl";
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this with a symbolic link

```
ln -s /path/to/my/app/WebCNP /Library/Perl/5.16/WebCNP
```

Not sure if this is the most elegant approach, but seems to work well for this app. Thanks everyone for your replies! This has been very insightful.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, I know, but there is a much more portable way.  When you install the modules, you need to do two things.

1. Add the installation path to PERL5LIB (i.e. PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:/My/Module/Path/lib) in your environment configuration (.profile or other files which get read on system initialization)
2. Add a PREFIX to your perl Makefile.PL call (perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/My/Module/Path)

It goes without saying that you need to make certain your Makefile.PL is written correctly.